# How do you express high proficiency in a succinct way?

Tags: phrases, idioms, idiom-requests

I heard the following phrase in movies:

> -- Do you know how to use A?
>
> -- I am a f****g **surgeon** with A

I like it a lot, but I can imagine a lot of people will not understand the meaning.

I would like to ask for something polite enough, that I could use in a cover letter.

In my country we say "A is like my right hand", but I do not remember anybody say that in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm **an expert at** us**ing** A.

I'm **an expert in terms of** us**ing** A.

seem polite enough.

Comment: I considered this, but it seems to imply that you **specialize** in A, and that you are possibly not very good at other things.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik why does being *"a f ___ (brain) surgeon at A"* mean you are equally capable of doing other things? Being as good as a "brain surgeon" in a particular field means you are specialized. Otherwise why would the expression exist?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Wrong.  There is no such negative implication with the word 'expert'.

Answer (score 4):

> adept — very skilled or proficient at something

This is a very good word.

Comment: +1, you are right, that is a good word. Welcome to ELU, user114814. When you get a moment click on this [Link](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the TOUR and also click on the HELP button on the right-side of the title bar and check –out the “HELP CENTER”, if you haven’t already done so. There’s a lot to learn about this site, such as how to ask good questions and provide good answers, all about "rep" points and how they effect "site privileges" . It’s well worth looking around. Anyway, enjoy yourself, and we’ll see you around.

Answer (score 1):

An "American*ism*" from the Washington Times:

> **Employee' needs more training** 
>   Oct 5, 2006 - He's a scanner-gun-toting cowboy who works the register ***like Bill Clinton works a crowd***. [Like Bill Clinton](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2006/oct/5/20061005-102457-4674r/)

And here are a few nouns that should be serviceable,

> **prodigy** *noun*: plural noun: prodigies
>
> • a person, especially a young one, endowed with exceptional qualities or abilities. "a Russian pianist who was a child *prodigy* in his day"
>   synonyms: genius, mastermind, virtuoso, wunderkind, wonder child, boy wonder, girl wonder
>
> • an impressive or outstanding example of a particular quality. "Germany seemed a *prodigy* of industrial discipline"
>
> *synonyms*: model, classic example, paragon, paradigm, epitome, exemplar, archetype; see, Google [prodigy](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=Prodigy+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=prodigy+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.0.13196...........0.D7gj51F77TU&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **genius** *noun*:; plural noun: geniuses
>
> 1. exceptional intellectual or creative power or other natural ability.
>      "she was a teacher of genius"
>
> *synonyms*: brilliance, intelligence, intellect, ability, cleverness, brains, erudition, wisdom, fine mind; see, Google [genius](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=genius+definition&oq=genius+definition&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i67j0i7i30l4j0i20j0i7i30l4.4658.4658.0.7673.1.1.0.0.0.0.99.99.1.1.0.msedr...0...1c..62.serp..0.1.98.Iwm6INcZtec)
>
> **savant** *noun*:; plural noun: savants
>
> a learned person, especially a distinguished scientist.
>
> *synonyms*: intellectual, scholar, sage, philosopher, thinker; see, Google [savant](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=genius+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=savant+definition&gs_l=hp..2.41l363.0.0.3.198472...........0.dkjQ8J62WYU&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: I wouldn't use the terms *genius*,  nor *prodigy* in a cover letter.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I guess that rules out virtuoso, magician, diva and whiz too, then.